# How to get the legacy paths in react-native-blob-util

Tags: android, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've been using rn-fetch-blob for my project so far but had some issues with it and would like to replace it with react-native-blob-util.

however, the latter implements media storage witch (to my understanding) changes paths from for ex: /storage/emulated/0/Download/ to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package_name>/files/Download/ on newer android versions.

but when I did some digging on the library source code I found a property called LegacyDownloadDir and also in the [release notes](https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/releases/tag/0.16.2) for the version 0.16.2 it said such properties do exist, but I can't find them.

I tried calling:

```
ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.dirs.LegacyDownloadDir
```

but it returns undefined and Typescript can't seem to find it.

am I calling it the wrong way? or do I need to configure something before it shows up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on android 12. For now I'm using `react-native-fs` for android and calling `RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath` which seems to give me the path to the general download directory.

For iOS it seems to require more steps. I first have to use `react-native-document-picker` and call `DocumentPicker.pickDirectory()` to let the user pick where they want to store the document, then use the resulting path to write the file `RNFS.writeFile(path, file, "base64")`

Answer (score 0):

No you're calling it correctly.
Seems like a bug (https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/issues/89)

Which Android version and device are you using?

I will take a look at it and see if there is a fix required.

Comment: I'm on android 12.

For now I'm using `react-native-fs` for android and calling `RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath` which seems to give me the path to the general download directory.

For iOS it seems to require more steps. I first have to use `react-native-document-picker` and call DocumentPicker.pickDirectory() to let the user pick where they want to store the document, then use the resulting path to write the file `RNFS.writeFile(path, file, "base64")`

Please let me know if you this as a good solution so I make detailed answer of it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problems yesterday in [0.16.3](https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/releases/tag/0.16.3)

Comment: Just tried 0.16.3 and ts no longer screams at me when using `ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.dirs.LegacyDownloadDir`, however it still returns undefined in runtime.
These are the permissions I have:
```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

Comment: Yes but this is expected.  It is a deprecated interface which might return undefined on newer devices.